# Postgresqlで配列型の値から特定の値を取得する方法。

Tags: sql, postgresql

環境：(PostgreSQL) 9.4.5

`SELECT ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'hoge'] AS fuga;`

この配列から真ん中のbarだけ取得したい場合、どのようにすればいいのでしょうか

PHP感覚で

`SELECT ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'hoge'][0] AS fuga;`

としたら

ERROR:  "["またはその近辺で構文エラー

と怒られてしまいました・・・

Answer (score 3):

確かに `[x]` で特定の要素を取り出すことができますが、

- 単純な列名である場合などを除いて、配列を表す式は括弧で囲む必要があります
  参考： [4.2.3. 添字](http://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.4/html/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-SUBSCRIPTS)
- 添字は1から始まります（範囲外の添字を指定するとNULLになります）
  参考： [8.15.3. 配列へのアクセス](http://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.4/html/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING)

ということで以下のようにすれば `bar` が取得できます。

```
SELECT (ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'hoge'])[2] AS fuga;
```